# Why can't I use my buds as 2-channel now, when I've always used them as 2-channel?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bluetooth, sound-volume, midi

I use Razer wireless earbuds with both my Mac computers and my iPhone, but recently, on my 2020 MBP with macOS Catalina 10.15.7 they just stopped outputting any sound and I can't, for some reason, use master volume slider in midi at all.

I have tried to un- and re-pair the buds but to no avail. I tried other headphones and speakers, and those all worked.  More mysteriously, the earbuds work on all of my other devices. I've also tried tampering with the format of the sound - I changed it to 1 channel (16-bit), and the Razer buds worked, but the sound was awful, like from a tin can.

Any theories as to why all of a sudden they appear as muted while using 2-channel format, and how to change that back?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it's always been that way, but I have no idea why.
If an output has a joint channel, like the older single speaker "built-in output" then it has a single master fader & the two separate channels are disabled.

[image]

If it has distinct channels, then the channels are active & the Master is disabled.

[image]

Comment: thank you, this makes the problem a little more clear, even tho still, I dont know why cant I all of a sudden use my buds as 2-channel, when it worked in the past without a problem...

Comment: I wonder if it may depend on how you have the audio format set… 32-bit 48k is definitely a 'hifi' setting [& tbh you really won't be able to hear that kind of quality in a headset of any sort]. but BT has 'grades' of connection, so I wonder if you drop that quality it may open up the possibility [Can't test, no BT headset here]

Comment: Interesting point, however, the drop menu doesnt provide any other choices than [1-channel 16-bit 16k] and [2-channel 32-bit 48k]. Is there any third party software you know of, that may provide further options? When I googled solutions for my problem I came multiple times across Soundflower, even though the posts were never about the exact problem Im having. What is your take on that app, could it possibly help with my issue?

Comment: Ive read about the app, but honestly, I didnt understand most of its functionalities...

Comment: If that's all it offers, that's likely all it can do. The 1ch 16-bit, 16k will be it's "telephone" mode, when it's being used two-way as headset & mic simultaneously. Soundflower isn't the way to go. It used to have a routing component, but not any more. A good consumer app for redirecting sound outputs is [SoundSource](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) [Rogue Amoeba make some very good sound apps, but they're not free]